# Twilio: GET number from XML

Tags: xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I want to get a number from a GET Response.

The Response looks like this (example number):

```
<Response>
 <Dial>+12345678912</Dial>
</Response>
```

I have created a Twilio Flow which has some code blocks and it has a GET Request, but i do not know how to get the Number from the GET Request into my forward call block.

**How do i get this number in my forward call block?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I assume you are using Studio when you say you have created a Twilio Flow.

If you are sending an HTTP request from a Studio Flow then you can add parameters in the widget. The parameters can be auto completed from the variables available in the flow. If you start typing `{{` the autocomplete box will drop down.

[image]

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I have noticed that you can access the body and other things. The Thing is my body has the phone number, but it has other numbers mixed within it.
P.S. I am currently not working on this task but my colleague is and she doesn't have StackOverflow.

Comment: You can access the `From` as well as the `Body`. Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: well yes, but it was giving me the number + some other numbers.
Also my colleague has figured out how to get the clean number, so i have to ask her how she did it and post it as the answer.

Comment: Ok, glad your colleague has sorted it out!